# Не печатает программа

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import sys
import collections

user = collections.namedtuple("User", "username midlename surename id")

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1 or sys.argv[1] in {"-h", "--help"}:
        print("usage: {0} file11 [file2 [... fileN]]".format(sys.argv[0]))
        sys.exit()

    usernames = set()
    users = {}
    for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
        for line in open(filename, encoding = 'Utf-8'):
            line = line.rstrip()
            if line:
                user = process_line(line, usernames)
                users[(user.surname.lower(),
                       user.forename.lower(), user.id)] = user
    print_users(users)


def process_line(line, usernames):
    fields = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    n = 0
    for b in line.split(":"):
        fields[n] = b
        n += 1    
    username = generate_username(fields, usernames)
    user = User(username, fields[1], fields[2],
                fields[3], fields[0])
    return user


def generate_username(fields, usernames):
    username = ((fields[1][0] + fields[2][:1] +
                 fields[3]).replace("-", "").replace("'", ""))
    username = original_name = username[:8].lower()
    count = 1
    while username in usernames:
        username = "{0}{1}".format(original_name, count)
        count += 1
    usernames.add(username)
    return username

def print_users(users):
    namewidth = 32
    usernamewidth = 9

    print("{0:{nw}} {1:^6} {2:{uw}}".format("Name", "ID", "Username",
                                             nw = namewidth, uw=usernamewidth))
    print("{0:-<{nw}} {0:-<6} {0:-{uw}}".format("", nw=namewidth,
                                                uw=usernamewidth))

    for key in sorted(users):
        user = users[key]
        initial = ""
        if user.middlename:
                initial = " " + user.middlename[0]
        name = "{0.surname}, {0.forename}{1}".format(user, initial)
        print("{0:.<nw}} ({1.id:4}) {1.username:{uw}}".format(name, user,
                                                              nw= namewidth,
                                                              uw=usernamewidth))



main()
```

Вот текст файла Data.txt:

```
 1289:Albert:Lukas:Montgomery:legal
 1234:Bob:Marly:Montgomery:sing
 1256:Andru:Martin:Landail:programs
 1235:Alex:Luter:King:legal
 1756:Djoan:Katy:Rouling:sing
```

Программа выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\programs\learning_program\generate_users_names\generate_usernames.py", line 67, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\programs\learning_program\generate_users_names\generate_usernames.py", line 17, in main
    user = process_line(line, usernames)
  File "D:\programs\learning_program\generate_users_names\generate_usernames.py", line 30, in process_line
    user = User(username, fields[1], fields[2],
NameError: name 'User' is not defined
```

Почему система не видит имя уникального списка User, который я определил с самого начала, подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: а где вы вызываете `main()`?

Comment: OOO!! Точно!!!!!

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: ЭТИ СООБЩЕНИЯ ОТНОСЯТСЯ К ПРЕДЫДУЩЕМУ ВОПРОСУ!!!

Answer (score 1):

В Python регистр названий объектов (переменных, функций, классов и т.д.) имеет значение!

Вы объявили `user`, а использовать пытаетесь `User` - такого объекта не существует.

Соответственно или объявите `User`:

```
User = collections.namedtuple("User", "username midlename surename id")
```

или используйте `user`:

```
usr = user(...)
# далее используем `usr`
```

Comment: А какую тогда функцию выполняет имя именнованного списка ("User")? И где мне его использовать?

Comment: @Бронеслав, имя в кавычках используется как имя класса при переводе объекта в строковой вид (например, при выводе через print): https://ideone.com/Vp1vfX